# Read transactions using fn_dblog after a full backup and server restart

Tags: backup, transaction-log

I need to retrieve transaction log data from a specific day or time in the past, even after executing a full backup and restarting the server.
While I have utilized fn_dblog and DBCC TRACEON(2537,-1) to identify inactive transactions, I'm aware that this information is lost after a full backup.
How can I effectively capture and retain these historical transaction log data for analysis, ensuring they are not lost during subsequent backups or server restarts?

Please note that I'm currently utilizing the MSSQLLogAnalyzer tool that uses fn_dblog to read transaction log files as mentioned in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274051/sql-server-how-to-decode-rowlog-content).

You can find the tool on GitHub at the following link:
[MSSQLLogAnalyzer](https://github.com/ap0405140/MSSQLLogAnalyzer)